# Mount USB Device in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, usb-storage, sd-card

I'm using a Siduction (a Debian derivative) on a Lenovo x230 laptop which has a built-in SD drive, and I'm trying to mount it to get some pictures of off an SD card. I've also tried connecting the camera via USB cable, and that is not working either for some reason.

When I plug in the USB cable I see the following in dmesg:

```
May  5 16:25:16 kernel: [  289.730351] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci 
May  5 16:25:16 kernel: [  289.817259] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0427 
May  5 16:25:16 kernel: [  289.817268] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
May  5 16:25:16 kernel: [  289.817273] usb 1-1.2: Product: NIKON DSC D3100 
May  5 16:25:16 kernel: [  289.817276] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: NIKON 
May  5 16:25:16 kernel: [  289.817280] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 000003512534 
May  5 16:25:16 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2" 
May  5 16:25:16 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
```

But I can't see any new devices under /dev which I can mount. The same goes for the SD card reader. When I insert the card, I can see the following log messages, but no device.

```
May  5 16:40:19 kernel: [ 1192.452637] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address b368 
May  5 16:40:19 kernel: [ 1192.452879] mmcblk0: mmc0:b368 SDC   30.2 GiB 
May  5 16:40:19 kernel: [ 1192.454515]  mmcblk0: p1
```

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `dmesg` output looks normal for an SD card - mine is the same way (Lenovo t530)

You should be able to also see it with `# fdisk -l` and you'll see the `mmcblk*`

So to mount that would look like:

```
# mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/YOURMOUNTPOINT
```

Unless you have an odd formatting, I would doubt you'll see any issues there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try one of these:

1. Using `blkid`:

   As a root, run

   ```
   # blkid
   ```

   or as a regular user, run

   ```
   $ /sbin/blkid
   ```

   It should list all your block devices, with bunch of information about them, including the path to the device.
2. Look under `/dev/disk/`:

   ```
   $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
   ```

   should list your device, together with the actual device file to which the symbolic link points.